# Graphics.DrawLine lags when PictureBox SizeMode is set to Zoom

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have a winforms app where I draw on an image in a picturebox. The drawing part works really well, except for lag when `PictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`. The reason I set the SizeMode to Zoom is so I could zoom in and out of the image while preserving memory. Is there any way to speed up the drawing process?

The code for the PictureBox's Paint method looks like so:

```
pen = new Pen(color, 5);
solidBrush = new SolidBrush(solid);
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(PictureScale, PictureScale);

foreach (List<Point> polygon in Polygons)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, polygon.ToArray());
}

if (NewPolygon != null)
{
  Pen pp = new Pen(color, 5);
  if (NewPolygon.Count > 1)
  {
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pp, NewPolygon.ToArray());
  }
  if (NewPolygon.Count > 0)
  {
    using (Pen dashed_pen = pp)
    {
      dashed_pen.DashPattern = new float[] { 3, 3 };
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(dashed_pen, NewPolygon[NewPolygon.Count - 1], NewPoint);
    }
  }
}
```

The code allows the user to draw a series of points connected by some solid lines. After adding the first point, there is a dotted line going from the previous point to the mouse's current position. The program 'fills' in the line when the user adds a new `Point` NewPolygon is a `List<Point>` object, and the program adds a point every time the user clicks. Pol is a `List<List<Point>>` object which holds NewPolygon. I attached a GIF of the drawing process because an image is worth 1000 words. The lag in the gif is not noticeable at all in different size modes.

[image]

The `if (NewPolygon.Count > 1)` loop draws solid lines between at least 2 points. The `if (NewPolygon.Count > 0)` draws a dotted line between `spot` and `NewPoint` when there is at least one point.

**EDIT : full drawing code**

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    bool drag = false;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point spot = new Point((int)((float)(e.Location.X) / PictureScale), (int)((float)(e.Location.Y) / PictureScale));
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
            drag = true;
        }
        else
        {
                if (NewPolygon != null)
                {
                    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        if (NewPolygon.Count > 1)
                        {
                            int counter = NewPolygon.Count;
                            Polygons.Add(NewPolygon);
                        }
                        NewPolygon = null;
                    }
                    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                    {

                        if (NewPolygon[NewPolygon.Count - 1] != spot)
                        {
                            NewPolygon.Add(spot);
                            scaffolds.Add(new Rectangle(spot.X - 3, spot.Y - 3, 6, 6));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NewPolygon = new List<Point>();
                    NewPoint = spot;
                    NewPolygon.Add(spot);
                    scaffolds.Add(new Rectangle(spot.X - 3, spot.Y - 3, 6, 6));
                }
            }
        //this.Capture = true;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (drag)
        {
            pictureBox1.Top += e.Y - y;
            pictureBox1.Left += e.X - x;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        }
        else
        {
            if (NewPolygon == null)
                return;
            NewPoint = new Point((int)((float)(e.Location.X) / PictureScale), (int)((float)(e.Location.Y) / PictureScale));
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(PictureScale, PictureScale);

        foreach (Rectangle rect in scaffolds)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
        }

        foreach (List<Point> polygon in Polygons)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, polygon.ToArray());
        }

        if (NewPolygon != null)
        {
            Pen pp = new Pen(color, 5);

            if (NewPolygon.Count > 0)
            {
                if (NewPolygon.Count > 1)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pp, NewPolygon.ToArray());
                }
                using (Pen dashed_pen = pp)
                {
                    dashed_pen.DashPattern = new float[] { 3, 3 };
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(dashed_pen, NewPolygon[NewPolygon.Count - 1], NewPoint);
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: There are missing pieces here. The lag appears to be generated by the procedure that calculates the current mouse pointer position and invalidates the Control. You should show this part, IMO (are you using a Timer, maybe). It's also not clear why you have `if (NewPolygon.Count > 1)` and right after `if (NewPolygon.Count > 0)` which also matches the previous condition (also because `NewPolygon` should hold the new line coordinates). So, what is `NewPoint` doing here? Isn't it the last Point in `NewPolygon`?

Comment: `solidBrush` is set here but it appears to be a Field or a Property, as the previous Pen. If these are fields, change them to properties and dispose of them when the Form closes. The other object you create in-place, you also dispose of in -place. The SolidBrush appears to be used to draw the Dots. Post that code, too, so it's clear how the Dots and the Lines and synched.

Comment: I actually never draw anything in this code with solidBrush so it shouldn;t be there. I also added some more code to make it clearer

Comment: Your posted code doesn't produce anything.  Give us code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I added the code in it's full form, and the variables ```NewPolygon, Polygons, NewPoint, pen, color, and scaffolds``` are global variables

Comment: Use the @ sign with the user name in comments in order to send that user a notification.  The posted code doesn't lag for me.  What are the dimensions of that image?

Comment: @LarsTech thank you for that notification hint. Its kinda weird because there is no lag when the picturebox is blank, and my picture is 2700x1800 px. I'm using the Zoom SizeMode because I'm basically just resizing the picturebox to "zoom" the image like so: ```pictureBox.Size = new Size(originalWidth*scale, originalHeight*scale);```     The picturebox is inside a panel with a set size and autoscroll set to true

Comment: Your image is too big.  You would have to re-think your approach to only display the visible part of the image, so that there are fewer pixels in play.